# Mate Desktop freezes on login

Tags: command-line, login, lightdm, mate, ubuntu-mate

I got a new laptop, and swapped my hard drive into it. it booted right up. when I log in with my typical user account, the screen goes black, and it eventually shuts down.
I can log in via the terminal, and things go normally until I try to run `startx`, and xauthority crashes or something. actually, running startx will also kill my terminal.

but I had another user account, and I logged in with that, both from the command line, then running startx, and via lightdm. both work fine. So I have one user acount that crashes on login.

why would that be? I looked at .profile, and .bashrc, nothing odd there. I have an nvidia 1060 GPU in the new laptop. its not ideal, but I can run for now, I haven't lost anything, but I'd like to know why one user can log in to the desktop environment, but another cant. OS is Ubuntu Mate 20.04.

So it turns its just Mate that crashes, I installed Cinamon, and some other desktop environments, and I can boot and login fine with those. So then I tried reinstalling `sudo apt-get remove`, Mate, but the issue persists. I really prefer Ubuntu Mate as a desktop environment though.

Comment: Any clues in the user's `~/.xsession-errors` file?

Comment: there is, I'll have to updare my question, but it looks like caja and gtk have loads of permission denied requests.

Comment: You have to check permissions for dot-files and dot-directories in the home folder of problematic user.

Comment: @N0rbert, what should the permissions be?

Comment: @j0h the user and group should be yours ($USER), permissions are usually at least `rwx------` or `rwxrwxrwx` as max.